# If a String containing a number bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, string, int

I want to find if given String "99999999999999999999999999" or any massive number which would not fit in any datatype.I would like to find if that number is bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

```
BigInteger maxInt = BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
BigInteger value = new BigInteger("whatever");

if (value.compareTo(maxInt) > 0)
{
    // larger
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can call `parseInt` and catch `NumberFormatException`, which will be thrown if the number is too large (though it will also be thrown if the `String` has non-numeric characters).

If you want to avoid the exception, you can run the following checks:

- If the `String` has more than 10 characters (or 11 if the first character is '-' or '+'), it must be larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or smaller than `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.
- Otherwise, call `Long.parseLong()` and compare the result to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 5):

You could construct a [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) object from the string and then compare that `BigInteger` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse it as an int and catch an exception or BigInteger, or you can do a String comparison.

```
static final String MAX_INT_STR = Integer.toString(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

public static boolean checkInt(String s) {
    return s.length() > MAX_INT_STR.length() || s.compareTo(MAX_INT_STR) > 0;
}
```

This could be used to avoid throwing some Exceptions before trying to parse it.

NOTE: This doesn't check that it only contains digits, but if it's a positive number it will check it is in bounds without parsing the string.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code to check if it's too big to fit inside an integer:

```
String num = "99999999999999999999999999";

try {
    Integer.parseInt(num);
} catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
    System.out.println("String did not fit in integer datatype");
}
```

This code will attempt to parse `num` into an integer, we can catch whenever that goes wrong and execute code when that happens (in this case a simple `println`).

From [`parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)):

> Throws: NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a
>   parsable integer.

Comment: If possible, it's better to avoid using exceptions for regular application control flow.